# mySQL: update Record / duplicate entry / collate / binary

Tags: mysql, binary, unique-index, collate

i'm having a field called `url` (varchar 255) which is set to `unique` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` as collation.

when trying to update a record to set this url: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Léa_(film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9a_(film))

i am getting a duplicate error because another record exsists having https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lea_(film) as URL
(without accent).

i tried to add `COLLATE utf8_bin` which gave me an error:

```
COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

i also tried converting the URL by using `(CAST 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Léa_(film)' AS BINARY)` but didn't help either.

is there a way or is the only solution changing the field collation to `utf8_bin`?

thanks

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE for your table and session charset/collation settings. *i tried to add COLLATE utf8_bin which gave me an error* Show where and how have you tried to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when trying to update a record to set this url: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Léa_(film)`
>
> i am getting a duplicate error because another record exsists having `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lea_(film)` as URL (without accent).

If such values must be NOT treated as duplicates then you must execute ALTER TABLE for to alter the column's settings and set according collation to it (for example, `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` or `utf8mb4_bin` - see `SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8mb4_%';` and select proper collation).